# wordpress-java library: Publish a post in specific category

Tags: java, wordpress

There is a library: https://github.com/canbican/wordpress-java

How to publish a post into a specific WP Category? For Example
Category named "General". How to publish a post into General category?

Here is my code:

```
        Post recentPost = new Post();
        recentPost.setPost_parent(2);
        term1.setTaxonomy("General"); //This parameter does not post in category of General
        recentPost.setPost_title(title);
        recentPost.setPost_content("Test description");
        recentPost.setPost_status("draft");
        recentPost.setPost_parent(9);
        Integer result = wp.newPost(recentPost);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final Term term1 = wp.getTerm("category", 2);
        final Term term2 = wp.getTerm("category", 3);

        Post recentPost = new Post();
        recentPost.setTerms(Arrays.asList(new Term[] {term1, term2}));
//        recentPost.setPost_parent(3);
        recentPost.setPost_title(title);
        recentPost.setPost_content("Test description");
        recentPost.setPost_status("draft");
        recentPost.setPost_parent(9);
//        recentPost.setPost_thumbnail("sd");
        Integer result = wp.newPost(recentPost);
```